# Unable to stop TOSHIBA TransMemory

Tags: 12.04, usb

I have a USB,when I choose safety remove, occur this error message.How to solve the problem?

Unable to stop TOSHIBA TransMemory

```
Error detaching: helper exited with exit code 1: Detaching device /dev/sdb
USB device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2)
SYNCHRONIZE CACHE: synchronize cache(10):  Fixed format, current;  Sense key: Key=9
 Additional sense: Logical unit not ready, cause not reportable
  Info fld=0x0 [0] 
FAILED: No such file or directory
(Continuing despite SYNCHRONIZE CACHE failure.)
STOP UNIT: start stop unit: transport: Host_status=0x07 [DID_ERROR]
Driver_status=0x00 [DRIVER_OK, SUGGEST_OK]
```

FAILED: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try manually unmounting the usb drive from the terminal.

**Identify**

First you will need to know the mount point or the device. You have a few options but in your case I think the first will tell you what you need to know.

1.To see information about currently mounted systems, simply run:

```
mount
```

2.To see a list of your USB devices (the vendor and device ID's), run:

```
lsusb
```

3.To see all attached storage devices and their partitions, run:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

**Unmounting**

Unmounting is done through the "umount" command, which can be given a device or a mount point

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

or:

```
sudo umount /media/external
```

Would both unmount the filesystem on /dev/sdb1 if it is mounted on /media/external.

Remember that a filesystem cannot be in use when it is unmounted, otherwise umount will give an error. If you know it is safe to unmount a filesystem you can use:

```
sudo umount -l /mountpoint
```

To do a "lazy" unmount

**Reference Links**

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB